# Generating Random numbers in PHP Array

Tags: php, range

I have the following code:

```
<?php

function randomGen($min, $max, $quantity) {
    $numbers = range($min, $max);
    shuffle($numbers);
    return array_slice($numbers, 0, $quantity);
}




for ($row = 0; $row < 5; $row++) {
  echo "<p><b>Set: $row</b></p>";

print_r(randomGen(1,36,6));
}
//}//}
?>
```

which for example outputs:

```
Set: 0
Array ( [0] => 32 [1] => 35 [2] => 22 [3] => 29 [4] => 8 [5] => 17 ) 
Set: 1
Array ( [0] => 25 [1] => 28 [2] => 8 [3] => 30 [4] => 13 [5] => 9 ) 
Set: 2
Array ( [0] => 24 [1] => 31 [2] => 33 [3] => 28 [4] => 2 [5] => 32 ) 
Set: 3
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 6 [2] => 33 [3] => 2 [4] => 14 [5] => 29 ) 
Set: 4
Array ( [0] => 17 [1] => 25 [2] => 6 [3] => 15 [4] => 24 [5] => 22 )
```

However I Would like for the result to appear as: only the number, Example:

```
32 35 22 29 8 17
```

ETC, how can I go about removing them

Comment: `implode(" ", randomGen(1,36,6))` is that what you want?

Comment: Well when I tried the implode(" ", randomGen(1,36,6)) it doesn't return any values

Comment: implode by itself just returns a string, you need to echo that out of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use [`print_r()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) -- this function inherently prints the index as well.

```
$array = randomGen(1,36,6);
foreach($array as $key => $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

`$key` is the index you don't want; I included that for educational purposes.

```
$array = randomGen(1,36,6);
foreach($array as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: Totally Understand Thanks a lot for the Explanation. Really Amazing